# How to get serial number of USB-Stick in C#

Tags: c#, usb, usb-drive

How do I get the internal serial number of a USB-Stick or USB-HardDrive in C#?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
// add a reference to the System.Management assembly and
// import the System.Management namespace at the top in your "using" statement.
// Then in a method, or on a button click:

ManagementObjectSearcher theSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");
foreach (ManagementObject currentObject in theSearcher.Get())
{
   ManagementObject theSerialNumberObjectQuery = new ManagementObject("Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag='" + currentObject["DeviceID"] + "'");
   MessageBox.Show(theSerialNumberObjectQuery["SerialNumber"].ToString());
}
```

*Source: [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/f4447ed3-7e5f-4635-a28a-afff0b620156/](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/f4447ed3-7e5f-4635-a28a-afff0b620156)*

Comment: great job i got serial number how do i get instance id of the usb.

Answer (score 9):

A solution using Win32 [is described here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090328094546/http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/USB_SerialNumbers.htm)

Edit: the original link seems to have gone missing. The above is a cached copy, and the author also wrote some sample code in VB.Net which is [still online here](http://www.emmet-gray.com/Files/AdminTools/USB_SerialNumber.zip).

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for something like this forever!

Answer (score 7):

I had problems with the solution offered by Yuval Adam as every USB stick I tried return blank on windows 7.

I solved this by just looking at the property PNPDeviceId on the current object.

E.g.

```
currentObject["PNPDeviceID"].ToString();
```

Not sure how valid this is but it worked for me on the 3 USB Sticks I tried