# USB pen drive identifer from c#

Tags: c#, usb-drive

I have a demo that runs off of a USB drive and I would like to prevent the simple case where some one copies the demo.  I was thinking that I could just get something specific about the USB drive like manufacture,size, firmware version and or identifier. Since we are putting the demo together and sending it out it could be tied to a specific vendor for the drive. I will probably be doing this using c#.

Comment: I won't post this as an Answer since I'm purely speculating, but can you retrieve the Serial Number for the USB drive itself, and check for that?  Con: Does the serial number change when you put the key into a different machine?  Con: Can the serial number be manually set?

Comment: (I.e. I'm referring to the Serial Number you see when you "dir x:")

Comment: Check [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123986/how-to-determine-usb-flash-drive-manufacturer) out. This appears to provide you with the manufacture details.

Comment: Serial numbers are fine if the demo is only being deployed to a single USB drive - but if this is for more general marketing, then obviously each USB pen will have a different serial!  Manufacturer may be the way to go, but as Stefan says it's not 100% secure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this you can get the serialnumber for the USB-stick and can code that in the application: [How to get serial number of USB-Stick in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450009/how-to-get-serial-number-of-usb-stick-in-c)

But whatever you do, someone can use reflector or some other program and take away that check from your program.

Comment: The average "Joe" is going to have a lot of problems trying to run a copied demo.