# Retrieve serial number from USB memory (Windows environment c++)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, usb

I would need to retrieve the serial number from my USB memory, namely the hard disk's serial number that the manufacturer assigns. For this reason I cannot use GetVolumeInformation() as suggested in some other threads. I would need to have the "unique" number

I kindly ask you if you can share an example in C++ and Windows environment (Visual c++)

Thanks!

Comment: Wrong assumption. USB serial numbers are unrelated to disk serial numbers. Even a USB mouse can have a serial number (in practice they don't because mice do not have identity, they're all equal)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get USB serial number c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096823/get-usb-serial-number-c)

Comment: thanks for the clarification of my post. Nevertheless I need to extract the serial number of a USB memory, since, correct me if I am wrong, it should be a unique ID.
I have already checked the post which you suggested, indeed there is an example in c++ for Windows environment, but I cannot compile it despite I used windows platform sdk

Comment: It _should_ be. The cheap Chinese stuff violates about half the USB spec, and it's only Microsoft's leniency that allows them to get away with that. In particular, do not expect USB serial numbers. But take one step back: WHY do you think you need those? (Possibly the subject of another question)

Comment: I need an unique hardware id which I could use in order to identify the hardware connected to my pc. Of course I cannot use only pid and vid. That's why I though that using the serial number of an usb memory (not Chinese! :-) ) it could work.

Comment: That's not a real _why_. I figured out that a unique ID is for unique identification. That's what the abbreviation stands for. The problem is that the identity of a USB storage device is defined more by the content on it (i.e files) than the carrier itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out this article:- http://oroboro.com/usb-serial-number/

```
#include <WinIOCtl.h>
#include <api/usbioctl.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>

DEFINE_GUID( GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DISK,   
             0x53f56307L, 0xb6bf, 0x11d0, 0x94, 0xf2, 
             0x00, 0xa0, 0xc9, 0x1e, 0xfb, 0x8b );

void getDeviceInfo( int vol )
{
   UsbDeviceInfo info;

   // get the device handle
   char devicePath[7] = "\\\\.\\@:";
   devicePath[4] = (char)( vol + 'A' );

   HANDLE deviceHandle = CreateFile( devicePath, 0, 
                                     FILE_SHARE_READ | 
                                     FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, 
                                     OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL );
   if ( deviceHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
      return;

   // to get the device number
   DWORD volumeDeviceNumber = getDeviceNumber( deviceHandle );
   CloseHandle( deviceHandle );

   // Get device interface info set handle
   // for all devices attached to the system
   HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs( 
      &amp;GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DISK, NULL, NULL,
      DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE );

   if ( hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )  
        return;

   // Get a context structure for the device interface
   // of a device information set.
   BYTE Buf[1024];
   PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA pspdidd = 
      (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)Buf;
   SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA         spdid;
   SP_DEVINFO_DATA                  spdd;

   spdid.cbSize = sizeof( spdid );

   DWORD dwIndex = 0;
   while ( true )  
   {
      if ( ! SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces( hDevInfo, NULL, 
                                          &amp;GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DISK, 
                                          dwIndex, &amp;spdid ))
         break;

      DWORD dwSize = 0;
      SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail( hDevInfo, &amp;spdid, NULL, 
                                       0, &amp;dwSize, NULL );

      if (( dwSize != 0 ) &amp;&amp; ( dwSize &lt;= sizeof( Buf )))
      {
         pspdidd->cbSize = sizeof( *pspdidd ); // 5 Bytes!

         ZeroMemory((PVOID)&amp;spdd, sizeof(spdd));
         spdd.cbSize = sizeof(spdd);

         long res = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail( 
            hDevInfo, &amp;spdid, pspdidd,
            dwSize, &amp;dwSize, &amp;spdd );
         if ( res ) 
         {
            HANDLE hDrive = CreateFile( pspdidd-&gt;DevicePath,0,
                                        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL );
            if ( hDrive != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) 
            {
               DWORD usbDeviceNumber = getDeviceNumber( hDrive );

               if ( usbDeviceNumber == volumeDeviceNumber ) 
               {
                  fprintf( "%s", pspdidd-&gt;DevicePath );
               }
            }
            CloseHandle( hDrive );
         }
      }
      dwIndex++;
   } 

   SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
   return;  
}
```

You get the device number by calling `DeviceIOControl()` with the handle to your device:

```
DWORD getDeviceNumber( HANDLE deviceHandle )
{
   STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn;
   sdn.DeviceNumber = -1;
   DWORD dwBytesReturned = 0;
   if ( !DeviceIoControl( deviceHandle,
                          IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER,
                          NULL, 0, &sdn, sizeof( sdn ),
                          &dwBytesReturned, NULL ) )
   {
      // handle error - like a bad handle.
      return U32_MAX;
   }
   return sdn.DeviceNumber;
}
```

Next here is a method to recognize if a volume is removable media (e.g. like a usb or firewire disk):

```
bool isRemovableMedia( s32 vol )
{
   char rootPath[5] = "@:\\";
   rootPath[0] = (char)( vol + 'A' );

   char szDosDeviceName[MAX_PATH];
   char dosDevicePath[3] = "@:";

   // get the drive type
   UINT DriveType = GetDriveType( rootPath );

   if ( DriveType != DRIVE_REMOVABLE )
      return false;

   dosDevicePath[0] = (char)( vol + 'A' );
   QueryDosDevice( dosDevicePath, szDosDeviceName, MAX_PATH );

   if ( strstr( szDosDeviceName,"\\Floppy") != NULL )
   {
      // its a floppy
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: Really need to include enough in the answer that it'll remain useful when that link dies...

Comment: thanks. Indeed I tried to use the example which I could find using http://oroboro.com/usb-serial-number/ but I cannot compile it, despite I used the correct libraries.