# Looking for c# code to get usb serial #

Tags: c#, windows, usb, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get serial number of USB-Stick in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450009/how-to-get-serial-number-of-usb-stick-in-c)

Does anybody have any suggestions, preferably something that would work across windows 7 and xp, I already tried the class posted here http://www.cfdan.com/posts/Retrieving_Non-Volatile_USB_Serial_Number_Using_C_Sharp.cfm however a serial number is never returned.

I understand that the serial number on a usb is optional but I have tried 3 separate usb sticks so I doubt this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/f4447ed3-7e5f-4635-a28a-afff0b620156/):

```
ManagementObjectSearcher theSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");
foreach (ManagementObject currentObject in theSearcher.Get())
{
   ManagementObject theSerialNumberObjectQuery = new ManagementObject("Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag='" + currentObject["DeviceID"] + "'");
   MessageBox.Show(theSerialNumberObjectQuery["SerialNumber"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me, and its ManagementObjectSearcher not ManagementObjectSearch

Comment: Yup, it was a typo and is now fixed. Either way, are you sure your USB sticks have serial numbers? Plus, this threads closed anyway so no one else can answer.